# Cant change uitextfield background color inside uisearchbar iOS8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

Im trying to change the background color of the `UITextField` inside of an `UISearchBar`. To do this, I have tried the following:

-This simple one-liner of code:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This for loop:

```
for (UIView *subView in _searchBar.subviews) {
    for(id field in subView.subviews){
        if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)field;
            [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
UITextField *txfSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I'd like to avoid changing the background image of the UISearchBar, so what's the new solution for iOS8? I've found no working answer on stack.

Comment: The third approach is working for me (devices and simulators, iOS 8.4). Is the `txfSearchField` nil?

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help I am not sure why it didnt work the first time. Maybe just needed to run the code twice or didnt re-run.